# Deadlock in Parallel.Foreach while using ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am facing deadlock error while using Parallel.Foreach.
I have 1000 records in datatable and i'hv created 5 threads to process it.
but when i'hv run this console application then after some records processed it will create a deadlock and no other records will process.
Here is my code :

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt1.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, dr =>
{
    cmd1.CommandText = $"Update AuditMessage set Status=1" +
        $" where SXAEASCoreAuditMessageID ='{Convert.ToString(dr["AuditMessageID"])}' ";
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.Transaction = trans;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                          
});
```

Comment: So in multiple threads at once, you're trying to modify the same `SqlCommand` object. Isn't that kind of like 5 people trying to drive the same car at the same time, all with different destinations in mind?

Comment: What DBMS are you having ?

Comment: You need to rethink this, parallel for each is not suitable for IO bound workloads to start with, additionally throwing more threads at a database is seldom the fix to anything. Databases are threaded internally and are more efficient at allocating resources then you are (the client). As such this turns into an X/Y problem... You have an issue you're trying to solve, when in fact your issue is actually something else. Heading down this path will be a refactor waiting to happen. I would suggest crafting a smarter query for the DB, and ditch the threading all together and use async

Comment: Related: [Deadlock in Parallel.Foreach while using SQL Transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675494/deadlock-in-parallel-foreach-while-using-sql-transaction)

Answer (score 2):

**Why does it lock?**

Your problem is probably not database concurrency, but concurrency on the cmd1 object, which you are using for every thread.

You need to create a new SqlCommand for each of the threads, or in every iteration.

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt1.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, dr =>
    {
                  using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(connection))
                  {
                     cmd.CommandText = $"Update AuditMessage set Status=1 where SXAEASCoreAuditMessageID ='{Convert.ToString(dr["AuditMessageID"])}' ";
                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                     cmd.Transaction = trans;
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }                          
    });
```

**some basics on row/table locking.**

In case you are doing is on SQL Server, you are creating more overhead than speed out of this parallel processing. Every row modified will be locked by the DBMS, and eventually, when the overhead gets to high, it will commence a table lock, leaving your threads working sequentially anyway.

**so, forget about parallel.foreach here, and let the database do the efficiency optimizing**

You could select the AuditMessageIds into a List.
Then cut it to pieces of 100 or so, and then make a smarter update query, like a query which does the update to status 1 in bulks..

```
where SXAEASCoreAuditMessageID IN ...
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2017, when i have tried solution as you given above it works but not all my records getting updated, in above parralel.foreach i'm using sql transaction and select data from database and then that selected data i'm passing into parallel.foreach list and those records needs to updated with status = 1, but after trying your solution not all my records updated.

Comment: Please suggest, i want to use sql transaction in parallel.foreach, how can i use it?

Comment: I upvoted your anwer, although I am not sure that what you are doing is legal. According to Microsoft the `SqlConnection` class [is not thread safe](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/342a48c8-234d-4d3f-833f-9a2c15f027af/sqlconnection-and-thread-safety). So the `new SqlCommand(connection)` line inside the `Parallel.ForEach` lambda may be illegal.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, i think in this case it is legal, because there is one SqlCommand per Thread, however, since the code behind uses the same connection, it is possible that you are right, also, i doubt that parallel.foreach speeds up things here, because afaik, it is being sequentialized by the connection anyway. i wrote that in the original answer, but cut it out for to keep the answer more simple